# Reemplazar espacios en blanco con each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día, quiero reemplazar los espacios en blanco en la columna que dice "Apellido Materno" con un punto (.), pero estoy que aplico este código y no hay cambios:

```
$(".apeMat_Inter").each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).val() == "") {
            $(element).val(".");
        }
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table class="table table-bordered table-striped tbl-interesado">
    <tbody><tr class="tr-head-interesado">
        <th class=""></th>
        <th>
            DNI:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Paterno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Materno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombres:
        </th>
        <th>
            Especialidad:
        </th>
        <th class="th-asistencia">
            Asistencia:
        </th>
        <th style="display:none">
            Nombre del Archivo
        </th>
        <th class="th-certificados">
            Certificados:
        </th>
    </tr>

        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12132432</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">WWW</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">WWW</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12323424</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">DGDFGDFG</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">DFGDFGD</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">FGDFGDFGDF</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ASDFSDFSDSDSDFSDFSDFDS</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12365876</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">POMA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">PUENTE</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">JHOJAN</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12546898</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">RUPAY</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">TORRES</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">OSCAR HERNALDO</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12768567</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">MMM</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">MMM</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">14365768</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">SIERRA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">SIERRA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">EDWIN</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">15975364</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">CRUZADO</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">VALENCIA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">MARIA PATRICIA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">SDFLJKSHDF JSDGH FJHSDG FJ</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">32143243</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">ABCDE</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">.</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">ABCDE</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">34567890</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">AHSKJHJHSJ</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">JHJHGJHG</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">JHGJ HG</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">SDFVSDKJFH KSDJH KSDJHK</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">40541955</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">RIVERA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">ROBLES</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">OSWALDO DAVID</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">OOOO OOOO MMMM</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Comment: En el selector `$(".apeMat_Inter")` le estás diciendo que busque los elementos que tengan `class="apeMat_Inter"`, no veo ninguno en tu HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".apeMat_Inter").each(function (index, element) {
    let texto = $(this).html(); // Obtener el texto dentro del elemento
    texto = texto.replace(' ', '.'); // Reemplazar
    $(this).html(texto) // Modificar
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table class="table table-bordered table-striped tbl-interesado">
    <tbody><tr class="tr-head-interesado">
        <th class=""></th>
        <th>
            DNI:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Paterno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Materno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombres:
        </th>
        <th>
            Especialidad:
        </th>
        <th class="th-asistencia">
            Asistencia:
        </th>
        <th style="display:none">
            Nombre del Archivo
        </th>
        <th class="th-certificados">
            Certificados:
        </th>
    </tr>

        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12132432</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">WWW</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">WWW</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12323424</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">DGDFGDFG</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">DFGDFGD</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">FGDFGDFGDF</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ASDFSDFSDSDSDFSDFSDFDS</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12365876</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">POMA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">PUENTE</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">JHOJAN</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12546898</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">RUPAY</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">TORRES</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">OSCAR HERNALDO</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">12768567</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">MMM</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">MMM</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">14365768</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">SIERRA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">SIERRA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">EDWIN</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">15975364</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">CRUZADO</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">VALENCIA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">MARIA PATRICIA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">SDFLJKSHDF JSDGH FJHSDG FJ</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">32143243</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">ABCDE</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">.</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">ABCDE</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">ING. CIVIL</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">34567890</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">AHSKJHJHSJ</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">JHJHGJHG</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">JHGJ HG</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">SDFVSDKJFH KSDJH KSDJHK</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-interesado">
            <td class="td-seleccion">
                <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox" disabled="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="dni_Inter">40541955</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apePat_Inter">RIVERA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="apeMat_Inter">ROBLES</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="nombres_Inter">OSWALDO DAVID</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="especialidad_Inter">OOOO OOOO MMMM</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                <label>FALTO</label>
                <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
                <label>ASISTIO</label>
                <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
            </td>

            <td style="display:none">
                <label class="nombreArchivo_Inter"></label>
            </td>

            <td class="td-certificados" style="padding:0; padding-top:15px; cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;" title="Certificado NO generado">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:20px; color:grey">
                            </i>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

</tbody></table>
```